# Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature when importing google-cloud/storage

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-storage

So I have been trying to import google-cloud/storage in typescript(shown in image) and it keeps giving me that error. Doing  const gcs = Storage; doesn't throw and error, but I am not sure this is an actual solution.

Error message

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quick look at the declaration file ("go to definition" on `'@google-cloud/storage'`) suggests that the correct usage pattern is the following:

```
import { Storage } from '@google-cloud/storage';
const gcs = new Storage();
```